# What is the difference between Data Marshalling and DTOs?

Tags: marshalling, dto

I recently learned about Data Marshalling, and I did some research. The definition of DTO and data marshaling seem to overlap pretty much.

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Data marshalling is the action of taking data and converting it into a format that can be serialised (to be sent over a connection or stored). Data unmarshalling is the oposite, is about taking the serialised data and 'unmarshalling' it into something that can be handled in a nicer way by a language.

A DTO is a object that is used to represent the data that will be marshalled/unmarshalled (in object oriented languages). Often DTOs have no logic, so they are anaemic objects.

Usually, a well designed OO application will use DTOs, as the core domain often doesn't match to what is required to transmit. For example an incoming DTO could be broken into multiple objects; or a mutiple core objects could be assembled into one DTO to return as part of an API call.